# THREE JS OcclusionComposer issues "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, three.js

I am trying to recreate the Volumetric Lighting example from JMSWRNR ( https://codesandbox.io/s/github/jmswrnr/website-examples/tree/master/3d-header/volumetric-lighting?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js ) but I am facing some issues with Occlusion Composer.
I don't really know GLSL so debugging is very hard especially for a beginner like me.
Here is the GitHub Repo: https://github.com/RolandTeslaru/roland-teslaru-portfolio/tree/not-working
Main Code is in the components/HomeCanvas/Scene.ts

My guess its that the VolumetricLightCylinder.js shader is causing the issue because when I change

```
 worldPosition.xyz;
```

to

```
worldPosition
```

the error disappears.

```
import * as THREE from 'three'

export default () => ({
  lights: true,
  transparent: true,
  depthWrite: false,
  uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge([
    THREE.UniformsLib['lights'],
    {
      attenuation: { value: 25.0 },
      anglePower: { value: 10.0 },
      spotPosition: { value: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0) },
    },
  ]),
  vertexShader: /* glsl */ `
    #include <common>

    struct PointLight {
      vec3 position;
      vec3 color;
      float distance;
      float decay;
      int shadow;
      float shadowBias;
      float shadowRadius;
      vec2 shadowMapSize;
      float shadowCameraNear;
      float shadowCameraFar;
    };

    uniform PointLight pointLights[NUM_POINT_LIGHTS];
    uniform float viewMix;

    varying vec4 vColor;
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vWorldPosition;

    float _punctualLightIntensityToIrradianceFactor( const in float lightDistance, const in float cutoffDistance, const in float decayExponent ) {
        if( decayExponent > 0.0 ) {
            return pow( saturate( -lightDistance / cutoffDistance + 1.0 ), decayExponent );
        }
        return 1.0;
    }

    void main() {
      vNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);

      vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
      vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition;

      vec4 addedLights = vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
      for(int l = 0; l < NUM_POINT_LIGHTS; l++) {
        float dist = distance(pointLights[l].position, worldPosition.xyz);
        addedLights.rgb += pointLights[l].color *
          _punctualLightIntensityToIrradianceFactor(
            dist,
            pointLights[l].distance,
            pointLights[l].decay
          );
      }

      vWorldPosition = worldPosition.xyz;
      vColor = addedLights;
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: /* glsl */`
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
    uniform vec3 spotPosition;
    uniform float attenuation;
    uniform float anglePower;
    varying vec4 vColor;

    void main() {
      float intensity;
      intensity = distance(vWorldPosition, spotPosition)/attenuation;
      intensity = 1.0 - clamp(intensity, 0.0, 1.0);
      vec3 normal   = vec3(vNormal.x, vNormal.y, abs(vNormal.z));
      float angleIntensity  = pow(dot(normal, vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)), anglePower);
      intensity = intensity * angleIntensity;
      gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor.rgb, intensity);
    }
  `,
})
```

Comment: Post the full error. The link to the repo does not work., maybe it's a private repo?..

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem as yours. I guess the worldPosition doesn't be coped successfully. I've tested some ways and figured out the error comes from:

```
float dist = distance(pointLights[l].position, worldPosition.xyz);
```

So the worldPosition doesn't cope successfully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).